# How to update an item in calendar with SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

To give you a little bit of context what I am trying to achieve is a workflow that can check if an event is created or not. If it's not created than create it and store the ID in a column from the source list. If the event is created I'll fetch that event and update it.

My problem is how do I look up that event?

With this action

```
Create item in Public Team Calendar (Output to Variable: ListEvent )
```

I can save the event ID in ListEvent, but how can I retrieve it later to update it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So your workflow is going to start once. If it created the item in the calendar list, then you store the ID (ListEvent), which is the output of the creation process in the same list where the workflow ran. So you have this Id stored in the same item. You can use this ID in another action if you want, in the same workflow or another workflow, to update the calendar event, where the ID of the even is equal to the value stored in your current list item's column.

Comment: I already have the ID stored in a column. What I don’t know how to do is the search with the ID that is stored in the column. What is the action and the parameter to compare with the stored ID?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem if anyone is interested.

The field that I was looking for to search for the calendar event is the `GUID`. This field is the one that is equal to the returned value when I created the calendar event.